# javascript get value from a function

Tags: javascript, function

How to get token in a `function`? I want send it out of this function for an ajax processing.

```
<body>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    var token;
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({ appId: 'XXXXXXXX',status: true,cookie: true,xfbml: true,oauth: true});
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse){
                       if(response.status=="connected") {
                                token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                       }
            }
        });
    };
    alert(token);//undefined
</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: `token` is defined outside `fbAsyncInit` so there's no need to get anything from `fbAsyncInit`.  Do you want to be able to take an action when `token` is changed by `fbAsyncInit`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're executing an asynchronous request which may not be finished by the time your alert is executed. To fix your issue, simply call a function when the async method is complete:

```
var token;
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({ appId: 'XXXXXXXX',status: true,cookie: true,xfbml: true,oauth: true});
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse){
                   if(response.status=="connected") {
                            token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                            asyncComplete();
                   }
        }
    });
};

function asyncComplete() {
    alert(token);
}
```

Or, simply pass the value in instead of using the `token` variable:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({ appId: 'XXXXXXXX',status: true,cookie: true,xfbml: true,oauth: true});
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse){
                   if(response.status=="connected") {
                            asyncComplete(response.authResponse.accessToken);
                   }
        }
    });
};

function asyncComplete(token) {
    alert(token);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

it is an async call,  meaning ur function is called and the script does not wait for it to return before executing the next `alert` statement making the token value 'undefined' there.

What you can do is call the function you want to call like,

```
var token;
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({ appId: 'XXXXXXXX',status: true,cookie: true,xfbml: true,oauth: true});
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse){
                       if(response.status=="connected") {
                                token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                                alert(token);//should give correct value here
                                newFunction(token);
                       }
            }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize token, and when you attempted to initialize it you did so in an if block. So one of your if statements is failing its if check.

Comment: so how to initialize, so that I could get it?

Comment: While there could be a problem with the `if` condition, even if the `if` is correct, the request appears to be asynchronous, so it would still be `undefined` with the current `alert()` placement.

Answer (score 0):

Call your function in when this AJAX call completes...

```
if(response.status=="connected") {
    token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    YourFunction(token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `token` variable is being assigned asynchronously, so is only available once the request has been sent to Facebook for validation and a response sent back. If you need to run any other functions that require the token to have been set already, call them from the line:

```
token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
doSomeOtherFunction(token);
```